# Trying to create a camel webservice (Web Project) and deploy it in Jetty

Tags: java, web-services, maven, apache-camel, cxf

Trying to deploy camel web project into jetty, but not working..
please help

below is the applicationContext which gets loaded when deployed

> WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">
    <!-- Still need it for loading the CXFServlet -->
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint
        xmlns:c="http://www.test.com/wsdl/CamelSpring/provisioning/v1_0/interface"
        id="camel_spring-ws" address="/camel_spring-ws" endpointName="c:camel_spring"
        serviceName="c:camel_spring-ws" serviceClass="com.main.listeners.CamelSpring" />

    <camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">


        <route id="nite">
            <from uri="direct:start" />
            <process ref="testRoute" />
        </route>

    </camel:camelContext>

    <bean id="testRoute" class="com.main.GetMessageProcessor" />

</beans>
```

> WEB-INF/web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>helloworld</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>cxf</display-name>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

> POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nite.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>CamelJetty</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <camel-version>2.12.0</camel-version>
        <cxf-version>2.7.0</cxf-version>
        <spring-version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

`

> I'm getting this following ERROR while deploying it to Jetty Server...

```
1536 [Scanner-0] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camel-1:beanPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:753)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:789)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1343)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor.getResourceManager(Jsr250BeanPostProcessor.java:91)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(Jsr250BeanPostProcessor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:396)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1000)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl.<init>(CXFBusImpl.java:76)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:58)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:143)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus.<init>(SpringBus.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.cxf.Messages != org.apache.cxf.APIMessages
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:456)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils.createLogger(LogUtils.java:270)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils.getL7dLogger(LogUtils.java:212)
        at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.<clinit>(BusFactory.java:79)
        ... 55 more
```

Comment: What cxf version are you using? Try with latest if you were on an older one.

Comment: currently using camel-version:2.12.0 and cxf version:2.7.0
will try with camel-version:2.15.3 and cxf version:3.1.2 @Bajal